# Magento 2 REST API. List products with parent/child relation

Tags: magento, magento2

I looking for a way to list products with Parent/Child relation. 
API {{baseUrl}}/V1/products (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html#catalog) provides only product **sku** (**parent_sku** is missing). So, I can`t build parent/child relation in simple way.

I also aware about this API endpoint: {{baseUrl}}/V1/configurable-products/{sku}/children - but it`s extra request which I want to avoid due performance reasons...

Please advice.

Comment: But in configurable product shows one object which holds all  sub product id

Comment: sorry, but which one? I can`t see it...

Comment: check this object "configurable_product_links": ['sub product id']

Comment: But this object is not exist in {{baseUrl}}/V1/products API response